# How to sort an array of objects by numeric parameters?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
var arr = [{"name":"first", value:"170"},
{"name":"second", value:"150"},
{"name":"second", value:"250"}]
```

How can I sort it by value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a callback for the values.

```js
var arr = [{ "name": "first", value: "170" }, { "name": "second", value: "150" }, { "name": "second", value: "250" }];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
});

console.log(arr);
```